# Creation date is set as null by hibernate, when changes are made during persist operation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am creating a course object and persisting in H2 database using hibernate and setting the creation date using @CreationTimestamp annotation

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE_DETAILS")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdatedDate;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
// constructors and getter and setters
}
```

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CourseRepository {

 @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

public void play(){
     Course course = new Course("New Course");
        entityManager.persist(course);
        course.setName("Not null");
}
}
```

I am getting following entry in the database

ID      CREATED_DATE    LAST_UPDATED_DATE               NAME

1       null            2021-10-06 22:31:43.465         Not null

but when i change the code to

```
Course course = new Course("New Course");
        entityManager.persist(course);
        course.setName("Not null");
        entityManager.flush();
```

I am getting following entry in db

ID      CREATED_DATE              LAST_UPDATED_DATE         NAME

1       2021-10-06 22:38:37.941   2021-10-06 22:38:37.963   Not null

Why the creation date is set to null in first case.

Comment: Hi notFound, maybe I'm wrong. In your samples even I couldn't see course's name correctly initialized. Are they actual table rows or arbitrary values under name column?

Comment: Hi  nurisezgin, name is set via Constructor which takes name as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself quickly and it worked. I'm sharing actual codes, hope you can get benefit from them.

Firstly, here is my pom.xml. As you can use I'm using Java11 and from dependency perspective only I have h2 database and spring-data-jpa.

```
    <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then, the entity which is almost as same as yours.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdatedDate;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

}
```

And the last thing would be queries.

```
public void saveCourses()
{
    Course course = new Course();
    course.setName("Course New!");
    em.persist(course);

    Course retrieved = (Course) em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Course c")
                               .getSingleResult();

    System.out.println(retrieved.getName() + ", " + retrieved.getCreatedDate() + ", " + retrieved.getLastUpdatedDate());

    retrieved.setName("Course New2!");
    em.persist(retrieved);

    retrieved = (Course) em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Course c")
                           .getSingleResult();

    System.out.println(retrieved.getName() + ", " + retrieved.getCreatedDate() + ", " + retrieved.getLastUpdatedDate());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to preserve created_by and created_date

```
@CreatedBy
@Column(updatable = false)
private String createdBy;

@CreatedDate
@Column(updatable = false)
private Date createdAt;
```

Unfortunately I also couldn't find out *why* the fields are nulled on update, but this solution does prevent them from being nulled out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using `saveAndFlush(Entity)` instead of `save(Entity)` solved the problem.